# NullPointerExceptionProblem - OUYA development using Eclipse with AndEngine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, andengine

As my final year project for college I am developing an OUYA game using ODK with AndEngine GLES1 in Eclipse. I have some experience making Android games, but this is my first OUYA, so bear with me.

My problem is, on attempting to deploy to the OUYA, it sometimes succeeds, sometimes returns a NullPointerException.

My main activity extends BaseGameActivity, and I'm overriding all the necessary methods (onLoadEngine, etc).

So, first I create a member variable of type Vehicle, which extends Sprite:

```
private Vehicle mVehicle;
```

I set up a TextureRegion, etc for this in onLoadResources, then call the Vehicle classes constructor in onLoadScene:

```
mVehicle = new Vehicle(SCREEN_WIDTH/2.0f, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2.0f, mVehicleTexReg);
```

The mVehicle instance has an update method which is called in onLoadComplete after registering an updatehandler and overriding onupdate. I am using an override of onGenericMotionEvent to detect controller input and call the appropriate vehicle function (rotate, accelerate, etc).

My problem is this: roughly 3 out of every 4 times I try to run my code I get a nullpointerexception in the onGenericMotionEvent function (the pointer being my mVehicle). It seems to me that onGenericMotionEvent is firing before onLoadScene has had a chance to construct my vehicle. Below is my entire MainActivity class, as well as the LogCat output on the problem. It's probably something really silly, but any help would be hugely appreciated.

The code:

```
package *****.*****.ssr;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.IUpdateHandler;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.Debug;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;

import tv.ouya.console.api.OuyaController;
//import ie.itcarlow.C00113480.ssr.R.layout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int MAP_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int MAP_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int NUM_VEHICLES = 1;

    //private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;

    //Game Objects
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Vehicle mVehicle;
    private Track mTrack;

    //Construction Values
    private int mTrackRows = 5;
    private int mTrackCols = 5;
    private int mTrackTileSize = 400;
    private String mTrackLayout = "5000216661166611666140003";
    ArrayList<TextureRegion> mTrackTexs;

    //Controller Fields
    private float conDZ = 0.3f;

    //Visual Assets
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mVehicleTex;
    private TextureRegion mVehicleTexReg;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mTrackStraightTex;
    private TextureRegion mTrackStraightTexReg;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mTrackBendTex;
    private TextureRegion mTrackBendTexReg;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mTrackEmptyTex;
    private TextureRegion mTrackEmptyTexReg;

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);       
        //setContentView(layout.game);      
        return new Engine
                (new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, 
                        new RatioResolutionPolicy(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
                        this.mCamera));     
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        //asset paths
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("vfx/");

        this.mTrackTexs = new ArrayList<TextureRegion>();

        //visuals
        this.mVehicleTex = new BitmapTextureAtlas(64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mVehicleTexReg = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                this.mVehicleTex, this, "vehicle.png", 0, 0);

        this.mTrackStraightTex = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mTrackStraightTexReg = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                this.mTrackStraightTex, this, "straight.png", 0, 0);
        this.mTrackBendTex = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mTrackBendTexReg = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                this.mTrackBendTex, this, "bend.png", 0, 0);
        this.mTrackEmptyTex = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mTrackEmptyTexReg = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                this.mTrackEmptyTex, this, "empty.png", 0, 0);

        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mVehicleTex, this.mTrackStraightTex,
                this.mTrackBendTex, this.mTrackEmptyTex);

        this.mTrackTexs.add(mTrackStraightTexReg);
        this.mTrackTexs.add(mTrackBendTexReg);
        this.mTrackTexs.add(mTrackEmptyTexReg); 

    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        Debug.d("Calling OnloadScene");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(); 
        //final Vector2 v = Vector2Pool.obtain(0,0);
        //mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(v, false);
        //Vector2Pool.recycle(v);
        //scene.registerUpdateHandler(mPhysicsWorld);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Sprite>> trackTexs;
        //create game objects
        mVehicle = new Vehicle(SCREEN_WIDTH/2.0f, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2.0f, mVehicleTexReg);  
        mTrack = new Track(mTrackRows, mTrackCols, mTrackTileSize, mTrackLayout, mTrackTexs);
        //attach to scene
        scene.attachChild(mVehicle);
        trackTexs = mTrack.getSprites();        
        for(int i = 0; i < mTrackRows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mTrackCols; j++){
                scene.attachChild(trackTexs.get(i).get(j));             
            }           
        }       
        //controller setup
        OuyaController.init(this);  
        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(final MotionEvent event){       
        float xOffset = event.getAxisValue(OuyaController.AXIS_LS_X);
        float lOffset = event.getAxisValue(OuyaController.AXIS_L2);
        float rOffset = event.getAxisValue(OuyaController.AXIS_R2);
        if(xOffset >= conDZ || xOffset <= -conDZ) 
            //Debug.d("Rotating");
            mVehicle.rotate(xOffset);
        else {
            mVehicle.rotate(0);         
            //Debug.d("Not Rotating");
        }
        if(rOffset >= conDZ || lOffset >= conDZ){
            if(rOffset > lOffset)
                //Debug.d("Accelerating");
                mVehicle.accelerate(rOffset);
            else if(lOffset > rOffset)
                //Debug.d("Braking");
                mVehicle.brake(lOffset);
            }
        else
            //Debug.d("Not Moving");
            mVehicle.accelerate(0);     
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed){
                OuyaController.startOfFrame();
                mVehicle.update(pSecondsElapsed);   
                mCamera.setCenter(mVehicle.getX(), mVehicle.getY());            
            }
            @Override
            public void reset(){}           
        });     
    }       
}
```

The logcat output:

```
Enabling debug mode 0

Exception dispatching input event.

Shutting down VM

threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group = 0x411fc300)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException

at ie.itcarlow.C00113480.ssr.MainActivity.onGenericMotionEvent(MainActivity.java:155)

at android.app.Activity.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(Activity.java:2459)

at com.android.internal.policy.imp1.PhoneWindowDecorView.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1887)

..................

.................

.................
```

Comment: Which line is 155? Something is null there.

Comment: Looks like your **mVehicle** is not instantiated yet. When is **onLoadScene** called? Probably after activity already started and reacts on user input

Comment: Why are some lines shown as comments, even though they're code? For example, `//setContentView(layout.game);`.

Comment: @hichris123 Have you never commented out code that you didn't want to run for whatever reason?

Comment: Nope. I just take it out of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about `AndEngine` but it seems fairly obvious from your description that its API does not guarantee that `onLoadScene` will be executed before a motion event is processed (also suggested by the asynchronous nature of `onLoadScene` + `onLoadComplete`).

Since the API cannot make this guarantee, you must be prepared to handle the case. This could be as simple as creating a `boolean sceneReady = false;` flag (`volatile` if necessary, again I do not know the details of this API), setting it to `true` when the load is complete, and ignoring motion events when the flag is `false`. Other options may be more appropriate for you.

Also, as an aside, you should verify the threading guarantees in the API documentation and double check that you are handling data in the appropriate manner - the nature of your issue raises a red flag that there may be other potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

Initialising many as possible in your onCreate() is the best way to handle these problems.